# Send radiobutton value to knockout observable

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button, observable

I'm trying to send the value from a radio button to a knockout observable. What am I doing wrong?
(I'm new to Knockout btw..)

```
function Question(data) {
this.question= ko.observable(data.question);
this.answers = ko.observableArray(data.answers);
this.explenation = ko.observable(data.explenation );
}

function QuestionViewModel() {
// Data
var self = this;
self.questoin= ko.observable();
var questionNumber = 0;
self.currentAnswer = ko.observable();

self.nextQuestion = function() {
    $.getJSON("json/quiz.json", function(data) {
        var newQuestion = new Question(data[questionNumber]);
        self.question(newQuestion );
    });
    questionNumber++;
}


self.setCurrentAnswer = function(){
    self.currentAnswer = currentAnswerValue;
}
}

ko.applyBindings(new QuestionViewModel());


<ul data-bind="foreach: question">
            <li>
                <text data-bind="text: question">
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul data-bind="foreach: answers">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radioAnswer" data-bind="checked: $root.setCurrentAnswer, value: currentAnswerValue">
                        <text data-bind="text: answerValue"></text>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
```

The "currentAnswerValue" is 'true' or 'false' and is set with json. (the value is correct, it works when I try):

```
<text data-bind="text: currentAnswerValue"></text>
```

Comment: Is this the real code? Please provide the real code if not

Comment: Well.. the real code is in dutch so it could be hard to understand. 
But there's no difference between this code and the real code except the names. And there's a lot more code in the real javascript file, but I can't see how the other code could contribute to the "problem" since it's just a class, $.json, ...

Comment: The problem with this code is that it won't compile... there are mistakes

Comment: Give me 5 mins and i'll post my whole code.

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="radioAnswer" data-bind="click: setCurrentAnswer, value: currentAnswerValue">` - there should be comma after setCurrentAnswer

Comment: As you can see I did that in my real code. Forgot it with copying it.
Don't focus on typo's btw.. There could be some in them, but I guess thats not the problem I get all my values in my html (typo's came there with translating from dutch to english.)

Comment: Where is `currentAnswerValue` declared? Couldn't find it.

Comment: That's the value from my radio button which I would like to send to my "currentAnswer".

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: It's not easy to read through the code as one could not which code is right or wrong. Like what is "vaarg"?

Comment: If I'm correct, that's not the way to send the value attribute from the radioButton to the viewmodel. I could be wrong though..
Well, everything works. I just have to send the "value" attribute from the radio button to the viewmodel.)

Sorry I forgot to translate "vraag" it is: "questions" :)

Comment: Then I get "currentAnswer is not defined;
changed it to $root.currentAnswer and haven't got "not defined" anymore. But it seems the "AnswerValue" isn't set to the value from "currentAnswerValue"

Comment: try `<input type="radio" name="radioAnswer" data-bind="checked: answerValue, value: currentAnswerValue" />`. I have tried to replicate what you have with no success

Comment: Didn't work either.
The problem actually is: How can I get the value from the radioButton back to the viewmodel, if the value from the radio button is set with data-binding. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer part of getting the choice:

**HTML:**

```
Question:
<ul data-bind="foreach: answers">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="group" data-bind="value: itemName, checked: $root.currentAnswer" /> <span data-bind="text: itemName"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<label data-bind="text: currentAnswer()"></label>
```

**JS/Knockout:**

```
var AnswerVM = {
    answers: ko.observableArray([{
        itemName: 'Answer 1'
    }, {
        itemName: 'Answer 2'
    }]),
    currentAnswer: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(AnswerVM);
```

Try it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/5bc66m2h/3/

Hope it helps!